# I am trying to execute a complex OrderBy within Linq, without having to call ToList() first

Tags: c#, linq

This works but requires that I execute an additional .ToList() too early, which is therefore slow...

```
public static Expression<Func<Admission, int?>> CurrentHouseSequence()
{
    return a => a.Person.Locations.OrderByDescending(l => l.TransferDate).DefaultIfEmpty(new Location()).Select(s => s.House != null ? s.House.Seq : null).FirstOrDefault();
}

var getCurrentHouseSequence = AdmissionRoot.CurrentHouseSequence().Compile();

List<Admission> adms = Db.Admissions
    .ToList() //done to prevent CurrentHouseSequence causing run time linq exception.
    .OrderBy( a => getCurrentHouseSequence(a)) 
    .Take(100)
    .ToList();
```

I then tried the following, inserting the extracted raw link from the function straight into the orderby, but get a runtime exception

> The entity or complex type  'DataContext.Location'  cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

```
List<Admission> adms = Db.Admissions
    .OrderBy( a => a.Person.Locations.OrderByDescending(l => l.TransferDate).DefaultIfEmpty(new Location()).Select(s => s.House != null ? s.House.Seq : null).FirstOrDefault())
    .Take(100)
    .ToList();
```

...Does anyone have any ideas how this could be achieved please ???

> so this was my final solution (thanks Rob)...

```
List<Admission> adms = Db.Admissions
    .OrderBy(a => a.Person.Locations.Any() 
        ? a.Person.Locations.OrderByDescending(l => l.TransferDate)
               .Select(l => l.House != null ? l.House.Seq : null)
               .FirstOrDefault() 
        : null)
    .Take(100)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You've got a bunch of null/empty set case checking that you don't need to do if you're using entity framework. Try this instead: `a => a.Person.Locations.OrderByDescending(l => l.TransferDate).Select(s => s.House.Seq).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Yea your right Rob, Specifically it was the DefaultIfEmpty(new Location()) construction that was causing the problem. Thanks for the quick response :-)

Comment: Essentially you have to call `ToList()` because complex expressions involving function call cannot usually be converted to SQL. By calling `ToList()` then only the part before that need to be supported by the SQL provider.

Comment: I do however need to consider null as EF [at least my version] does not currently handle this.  
So I have shown my final solution above.

Comment: If you want to call local procedures, or use non-poco classes without having to call ToList(), use AsEnumerable() before the calls to local items. Not sure though if this is more efficient. Maybe this still retrieves the complete table to local memory, but if might be smarter by querying a small number of elements, and ask for the next batch when enumerated

Comment: You can use functions if you use LINQKit, but converting the function into something EF can translate to SQL and putting it inline is probably the best for performance.